# css text swaping goes wrong inside flex container

Tags: html, css

Guys I am a total newbie. I learn through trying to solve problems which I create. I was reading about swaping one sentence and I decided to make this sentences swaped one after another and I failed so far. If original and a new sentence have same length it is easy. But lets assume they are different and need sometimes to go to another row to look like a traditional text. I can't solve it from several hours, in the attached screen there is a results and what I want. I was checking several websites and ideas. I managed to improve how it is showed on a screen, so it is more continuos but still it is not filling blank spaces or doesnt expand if the text is longer. I want after pressing a sentence, replaced it by another but text being continous without any kind of breaks. I based on this website https://css-tricks.com/swapping-out-text-five-different-ways/. Below is my html and css code.

Here is a drawing of my problem - [https://ibb.co/qkqMbwB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wAB7.png)

```
    
<html>  
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   <title>IGE</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="3code.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div  class="flexbox-container">
   
       
       <input type="checkbox" id="zdanie1Checkbox" />
       <label id="zdanie1" for="zdanie1Checkbox">Origxt1.</label>

       <input type="checkbox" id="zdanie2Checkbox"/>
       <label id="zdanie2" for="zdanie2Checkbox"> Original texsdsdsdsdsdsdsdsdddddd sdsd       sdsdsdsd sd sd  sdt2.</label>

       <input type="checkbox" id="zdanie3Checkbox" />
       <label id="zdanie3" for="zdanie3Checkbox">Original tsd ext3.</label>

       <input type="checkbox" id="zdanie4Checkbox" />
       <label id="zdanie4" for="zdanie4Checkbox">Orig    sdsdsddsinalText4.</label>

       <input type="checkbox" id="zdanie5Checkbox" />
       <label id="zdanie5" for="zdanie5Checkbox">Orixt54.</label>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and here is css

```
    body {
        padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
       
      }
     .flexbox-container {
       display:flex;
       flex-wrap:wrap;
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content:flex-start;
       align-content:center;
       
    
      }
    
      #zdanie1 {
        position: relative;
      }
      #zdanie1Checkbox {
        display: none;
      }
      #zdanie1Checkbox:checked + #zdanie1:after {
        content: "The outer layer is nearly melted through.";
        align-self: stretch;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0; 
        background: white;
        color: red;
        width:auto!important; /*this set the height to auto for those supporting it (not IE)*/
        width:500px; /*for IE, all others override it by the previous rule*/
        min-width:500px; /*for the ones that support it (all but IE)*/
        padding-right: auto;
      }
    
      #zdanie2 {
        position: relative;
      }
      #zdanie2Checkbox {
        display: none;
      }
      #zdanie2Checkbox:checked + #zdanie2:after {
        content: "The outer layer is nearly melted through.";
        align-self: stretch;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: white;
        color: red;
        width:auto!important; /*this set the height to auto for those supporting it (not IE)*/
        width:500px; /*for IE, all others override it by the previous rule*/
        min-width:500px; /*for the ones that support it (all but IE)*/
      }
    
      #zdanie3 {
        position: relative;
      }
      #zdanie3Checkbox {
        display: none;
      }
      #zdanie3Checkbox:checked + #zdanie3:after {
        content: "Soon the second layer will go.";
        align-self: stretch;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: white;
        color: red;
        width:auto!important; /*this set the height to auto for those supporting it (not IE)*/
        width:500px; /*for IE, all others override it by the previous rule*/
        min-width:500px; /*for the ones that support it (all but IE)*/
        
      }
    
      #zdanie4 {
        position: relative;
      }
      #zdanie4Checkbox {
        display: none;
      }
      #zdanie4Checkbox:checked + #zdanie4:after {
        content: "Then the scanner blinks silver and I’ve got what I came for.";
        position: absolute;
        align-self: stretch;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: white;
        color: red;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
        width:auto!important; /*this set the height to auto for those supporting it (not IE)*/
        width:500px; /*for IE, all others override it by the previous rule*/
        min-width:500px; /*for the ones that support it (all but IE)*/
     /* Non standard for webkit */
      word-break: break-word;
      -webkit-hyphens: auto;
      -moz-hyphens: auto;
      -ms-hyphens: auto;
      hyphens: auto;
      }
      #zdanie5 {
        position: relative;
      }
      #zdanie5Checkbox {
        display: none;
      }
      #zdanie5Checkbox:checked + #zdanie5:after {
        content: "The outer layer is nearly melted throu I almost didn’t notice.";
        position: absolute;
        align-self: stretch;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background: white;
        color: red;
        width:auto!important; /*this set the height to auto for those supporting it (not IE)*/
        width:500px; /*for IE, all others override it by the previous rule*/
        min-width:500px; /*for the ones that support it (all but IE)*/
      }
```

Comment: your question is still evry unclear to me. So you trying to swap text lines. When should the swap happen? how should it happen? what trigger for the swap do you intent to use. why use absolute positioning if you want to swap text lines? why sue input and labels for it? What is it that you actually trying to do in the end?

Comment: Alright thanks for a reply. The swap should happen after pressing a text line. After pressing it again - the previous sentence should appear. Regarding absolute positioning - this started to work only with this? I mean the checkbox. Or maybe it is so simple that it is an answer? I copied these inputs and labels from description from the link I provided - I think it is needed because of *invisible* checkbox. You can check a clear code as a 5th idea of an author. I modified it a bit so sentences will go sideways. I am trying to learn through solving, but this i cant

Comment: If you don't know the solution without thinking, don't bother. I don't want to steal your time, I thought maybe my problem is so easy to solve by others. Instead maybe I found a question no one else thought before ahahah. If I will figure out an answer I will post it here.

Answer (score 0):

There many ways to achieve it. The easiest way with the most varity to use would be the use of JS with an onlick event as shown below. In this case you have 2 lines used as a span so that they could be used within a paragraph. One is set to `display: none;` by default and therefor invisible. With clicking on the line, you trigger the script, that will hide the line with `display: none;` and show the other by changing it to `display: block;`.

```js
function show1b() {
  document.getElementById("line-1b").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("line-1a").style.display = "none";
}

function show1a() {
  document.getElementById("line-1a").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("line-1b").style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#line-1b {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<span id="line-1a" onclick="show1b()">This is the original text. Click on me to show the alternative text.</span>
<span id="line-1b" onclick="show1a()">This is the alternative text. Click on me to show the original text.</span>
```

CSS only

here you "mis-use" the input as a checkbox with the label. You hide the checkbox by using its id and `display: none;`. then you sue the id of the label with `:after` to use the attribute `content:`. Then you define the etxt that should be used. If the checkbox id is checked, then it will dispaly an alternative text as used in the sampel below.

```css
#line-1a {
  display: none;
}

#line-1b:after {
  content: "This is the original text. Click on me to show the alternative text.";
}

#line-1a:checked + #line-1b:after {
  content: "This is the alternative text. Click on me to show the original text.";
}
```

```html
<input id="line-1a" type="checkbox">
<label for="line-1a" id="line-1b"></label>
```

Comment: Thank you, I would be sitting with it next few days trying to figure it out. I am not skilled enough to help you with code but if you will have ever a need to translate something from polish or Russian to English send me a private message. Thank you once more. I doubt I become a programmer but I treat it as a puzzle for brain and sometimes it is too complicated for me right now.